# MySQL popular rows based on different time levels

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `photo` and `like`. I am trying to get popular photos based on number of likes in a day. So basically something like *'popular today'*.

```
SELECT
  p.id AS id, COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes \
FROM `photo` p \
  LEFT JOIN `like` li \
    ON p.id = li.photo_id \
WHERE
  li.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) \
GROUP BY \
  p.id
```

This works well when there are enough number of likes today. But if there are no likes in the past day, it will return no records.

I also want to change this a little. Is it possible to make levels? For example:
 Rank photos based on multiple days:

```
1. Get photos based on how many likes today
2. Get photos based on how many likes for last week
and so on...
```

So basically what this does is, let's say we need to get 30 items. First it will try to get rows based on how many likes there were today. It may be any number 20, 15 etc. Then it will get the remaining rows needed to get to a total of 30 but now will sort based on how many likes in a week.

```
So something like:
SELECT FROM photo SORT BY likes today, likes in a week ...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate different counts based on CASE, e.g. the likes of the last 30 days with counts for last day. last week and last 30 days:

```
SELECT
  p.id AS id
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN li.DATE > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN li.id END) AS daily_likes
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN li.DATE > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN li.id END) AS weekly_likes
  ,COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes
FROM `photo` p
JOIN `LIKE` li
    ON p.id = li.photo_id
WHERE
  li.DATE > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
  p.id
ORDER BY daily_likes DESC, weekly_likes DESC, total_likes DESC
LIMIT 30
```

I don't know on which definition your limit is based on, it might be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT
     p.id AS id
     ,COUNT(CASE WHEN li.DATE > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN li.id END) AS daily_likes
     ,COUNT(CASE WHEN li.DATE > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN li.id END) AS weekly_likes
     ,COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes
   FROM `photo` p
   JOIN `LIKE` li
       ON p.id = li.photo_id
   WHERE
     li.DATE > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
   GROUP BY
     p.id
  ) AS dt
ORDER BY
   case when daily_likes > 20 then daily_likes else 0 end desc,
   case when weekly_likes > 100 then weekly_likes else 0 end desc,
   total_likes DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: This makes sense. So your second bit of code for order sets minimum likes requirements? Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Your second code for ordering is not working for me, it gives me a `Reference 'daily_likes' not supported (reference to group function)` error

Comment: Yes, you're correct, only daily_likes > 20 and weekly_likes > 100 are used. But MySQL doesn't seem to support the alias in ORDER BY :-(  Changed my answer to use a Derived Table

Comment: One question though, `COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes` still counts total likes right? Or does it only count like for the last 30 days?

Comment: Based on the WHERE-condition it counts only the last 30 days. Of corse you can remove the comdition.

Comment: yup and this answer is perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried UNION?

[technet.microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

[Techonthenet.com](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29)

and NOT EXISTS

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

With UNION you can join select several select statements, as long the columns are the same

From the top of my head, something like

```
(select p.id as id,
       count(li.id) as total_likes
  from photo p,
       like li
 where p.id = li.photo_id
   and li.date > date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
   and rownum <= 10
 order by total_likes
 group by p.id)
 union
(select p.id as id,
       count(li.id) as total_likes
  from photo p,
       like li
 where p.id = li.photo_id
   and li.date > date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
   and rownum <= 10
   and not exists (select p.id as id,
                    count(li.id) as total_likes
                     from photo p,
                          like li
                    where p.id = li.photo_id
                      and li.date > date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
                      and rownum <= 10
                    order by total_likes
                    group by p.id)
 order by total_likes
 group by p.id)
```

Haven't tested this, but guess that something like this would do the trick

Comment: union does work but there's a slight problem : If a photo was liked today and and a week ago, the resulting rows will have the same photo twice

Comment: Please, find another resource than W3S because it's bad and you should feel bad if you promote it.

Comment: @user1768337. I have added a not exists with a subquery. Don't know what database you are using, and haven't tested this script - but you could play with it

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the number of weeks elapsed between today and the 'like' date and group by them.

```
SELECT
  p.id AS id, COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes, period \
FROM `photo` p \
  LEFT JOIN `like` li \
  ON p.id = li.photo_id \
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(li.date, now())+7)%7 AS period \
GROUP BY \
  p.id, period
ORDER by period, total_likes DESC 
LIMI 30
```