# Sphinxsearch maintain sql ordering

Tags: sphinx

So I have a query similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462040/1768337 And as you can see, the rows are already ordered according to likes. Let's say I create an index using the sql statement in the link above. Is there a way to output exactly what this sql statement gives? That is, maintain the ordering set in the sql statement? I also tried to rank the rows like the following,

```
source popular
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = --------
    sql_user        = --------
    sql_pass        = --------
    sql_db          = --------
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = \
        SET @rank=0; \
        SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank \
        FROM \
         ( \
           SELECT p.id AS id, p.search AS search, COUNT(CASE WHEN li.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN li.id END) AS daily_likes, COUNT(CASE WHEN li.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN li.id END) AS weekly_likes, COUNT(li.id) AS total_likes \
           FROM `photo` p \
           JOIN `like` li \
               ON p.id = li.photo_id \
           WHERE \
             li.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) \
           GROUP BY \
             p.id \
          ) AS dt \
        ORDER BY \
           case when daily_likes > 3 then daily_likes else 0 end desc, \
           case when weekly_likes > 5 then weekly_likes else 0 end desc, \
           total_likes DESC \
        LIMIT 30

    sql_attr_uint       = daily_likes
    sql_attr_uint       = weekly_likes
    sql_attr_uint       = total_likes
    sql_attr_uint       = rank

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id=$id
}
```

I tried this so that I could later use something like `$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@relevance DESC, rank ASC');`. However, it seems custom variable doesn't work in sphinx.

So my issue is to index a sql statement and exactly output it using sphinx (php api) - by even maintaining the sql ordering.

Comment: Did you define 'rank' as a `sql_attr_uint`?

Comment: @barryhunter yes I did. The indexer gives me an error like this: `ERROR: index 'popular': sql_query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank`

Comment: Well you've must have some sort of error in your config file. It would help to include your file. maybe use pastebin.com and remember to remove your db credintials.

Comment: @barryhunter I have updated my question. Please note that indexer works perfectly if I remove `SET @rank=0; \ ` and `, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank`

Comment: Ah yes. the SET should be in sql_query_pre not sql_query itself.

Comment: @barryhunter that was perfect! I have added your answer to this question now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks to [barryhunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65548/barryhunter) (The Savior) for helping out with this problem. As he mentions in his comments `SET` should be in `sql_query_pre`. So my `conf` file would look something like:

```
sql_query_pre   = SET @rank=0
sql_query       = \
    SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank \
    FROM \
     ( \
```